# Fail to package an app using Briefcase (BeeWare) and PyQt5

Tags: python, macos, pyqt5, beeware

I have build a desktop application on macOS ([macOS v13.4.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Ventura) (Ventura) - Intel processor) using Briefcase (BeeWare and PyQt5.
It runs well when started with 'briefcase dev'.

However, when I tried to package it, it fails with the following error at the step 'briefcase run':

[image]

Before starting, I have created a virtualenv using [venv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html)
(python3 -m venv .venv)

And I started it.
Everything that follows is within this .venv:

1. created my application and it runs fine when I start it with 'briefcase dev':

   [image]
2. Typed 'briefcase create' (runs ok).
3. Typed 'briefcase build' (runs ok).
4. When trying to run the app: 'briefcase run' it fails with the error:

   > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'

It seems like a pretty straightforward issue as the package is not found.
I am suspecting that something with virtual env is not, right?

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76761236/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To simulate a user who's installed your app on their own machine, `briefcase run` does not run the app in your current virtual environment. Instead, it uses a separate environment which contains only the packages listed in your pyproject.toml file.

So you'll have to add PyQT to the `requires` section of that file, and then run `briefcase run -r` to update the app's environment.

For more details, see https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-7.html.

Comment: Thank you. It works perfectly now. And thank you for sharing the link of the documentation ; that is very helpful.